# jQuery onclick add class and remove

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My code does not work correctly. 
I need to when user **click** on an `class="menubutton"` to tag `header` add classes `"hidden"`. When pressed again, the class was removed.

here is my Code.

**HTML:**

```
<header>
  <div class="headgeneral">
    <div id="headerlogo_dot">
      <div class="menubutton">
        <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
jQuery('.menubutton').click( function() {
    jQuery("header").toggleClass("hidden"); 
});
```

Comment: seems to work fine. on clicking the icon class does toggle

Comment: First your code is working. **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/3q2fyjLd/)**. Second, how do you expect to click on a `hidden` element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load jQuery listener after the document is loaded. You can do it like that:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
  $('.menubutton').click(function() {
    $("header").toggleClass("hidden");
  });
});
```

PS: The snippet doesn't load anything, try to fix it. Without that we can't give you more info.

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  jQuery('.menubutton').click(function() {
    jQuery("header").toggleClass("hidden");
  });
});
```

```css
.headgeneral{
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 30px;

}

.menubutton{
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
}

.hidden{
  background: #ffd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div class="headgeneral">
    <div id="headerlogo_dot">
      <div class="menubutton">
        <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

When using JQuery must written code within ready method and you didn't mention any style for your tag so that it is not visible in the page.